Permutations and combinations (p&c)
There are $8$ students from $4$ different schools ($2$ from each school). These $8$ students are to be put into $4$ different rooms ($2$ students in each room). Then what the number of ways in which exactly $1$ room contains students of same school?

For what it's worth, virtually every MathSE posted question that I have seen, that followed this article on MathSE protocol has been upvoted rather than downvoted.  I am not necessarily advocating this protocol.  Instead, I am merely stating a fact: if you scrupulously follow the linked article, skipping/omitting nothing, you virtually guarantee a positive response.

Hi, welcome to MSE ! As you are new, pl. know that for getting the necessary help,  you first need to edit in your efforts  even if stuck midway.

So we know that there are $4C1$ ways to choose one room to have 2 students of the same school. There are also $4C1$ ways to choose one school to have 2 students. This gives $16$ but we are not done. For the other $6$ students, there are just $6!$ ways to place them.
$16*6!=11520$

This is incorrect as when you are placing the last $6$ students it does not matter what order you place them.  You just need to choose $2$ for the first room, then $2$ for the next.
